# Wordpress block theme css for a section or div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that is built and styled (Enfold Theme), the last step in the process was embedding a 3rd party trading application that is served through javascript. The problem is the theme CSS is conflicting with the app. I started writing overiding CSS rules to fix the app layout but its becoming a near impossible task as well as the app vendor does periodic updates to their app which means my CSS may not work in future. I have tried iframes but this is also not an option as height needs to resize dynamically and the user session needs to be maintained locally.

I need to know if there is a way to create a custom page template where I can block the theme CSS on a section / div so that the app CSS remains in tact and served as it should be or if there is a plugin of sorts that can solve this.

Please if someone can give some direction or ideas it will be appreciated.

Comment: you cant do it ,As your css will be loaded for all elements EXCEPT for 1 section of div .if u block theme then all other elements wont have styling

Comment: Rather for that section use other CSS file and it will have all properties as !imporant; so it will override CSS of the current theme for that block

Answer (score 0):

In the header.php, you can distinguish other style and desired page template as follow;

```
if ( !is_page_template('your-template.php') ) {     
         //Normal theme css 
         } else {
         //customized css 
  }
```